# Find any number that can be square rooted and cube rooted.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Anyone can help with this?
It is like asking: $z^2=x $ , $ y^3=x$ where $y,z$ are integers.
we want to find $x$

Comment: $xy^3=x$ implies $x=0$ or $y=1$. Then solve $z^2=x$.

Answer (score 4):

Any sixth power will do, say

$$\;3^6=9^3=27^2\;,\;2^6=8^2=4^3\;,\;\;\text{or in general}\;\;\;n^6=(n^2)^3=(n^3)^2\;,\;\;\forall n\in\Bbb Z$$